# Quickest way to determine if a rectangular graph would be partitioned if a node is removed

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

I am working on an atmospheric simulation for a video game, and a problem I have stumbled into is that I need a cheap (in processing time) way to determine if a graph of nodes in a rectangular grid (each node is connected to up to four neighbours, NSEW) would become partitioned if I removed a particular node.

I have tried searching for ways of detecting if a graph is partitioned but so far I have not found anything that suits my problem. I have not taken advanced math courses and only have basic knowledge of graph theory so it is possible that I just have not been searching with the right terms.

If possible, it would be very very desirable to avoid having to search through the whole graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find articulation points using a modified depth first search - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biconnected_component. An articulation point of a graph is a node that, if removed, disconnects the graph. Every graph can be split up at the articulation points into biconnected components. If you are lucky, you just need to know whether a point is an articulation point. If not, perhaps splitting the graph up into a tree of biconnected components and analysing them will help.